# Pandas Convert a complex datastructure to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am querying an API and got the response like below

```
 {
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "outername": "OuterNameValue1",
        "value": {
          "columns": [
            {
              "innername": "innernamevalue1",
              "values": [
                "value1",
                "value2"
              ]
            },
            {
              "innername": "innernamevalue2",
              "values": [
                "value10",
                "value11"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "timestamp": "2020-01-01"
      },
      {
        "outername": "OuterNameValue2",
        "value": {
          "columns": [
            {
              "innername": "innernamevalue1",
              "values": [
                "value20",
                "value21"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "timestamp": "2020-02-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The number of objects inside the "columns" property would be dynamic. It can have more than 1 object.
From above response I want to pick specific property values and convert that to the pandas dataframe like below -

```
| timestamp | innernamevalue1 | innernamevalue2 |
| --------- | --------------- | --------------- |
| 2020-01-01| value1          | value10         |
| 2020-01-01| value2          | value11         |
| 2020-02-01| value20         |                 |
| 2020-02-01| value21         |                 |
```

So far I tried to normalize the response by creating a list of dictionaries like this -

```
r = data["data"]["items"]
t_r = []

for i in r:
    t = i["timestamp"]
    cols = item["value"]["columns"]
    for col in cols:
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict["timestamp"] = t
        temp_dict[col["name"]] = col["values"]
        t_r.append(temp_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(t_r)
```

this gives me a dataframe like -

```
| timestamp | innernamevalue1    | innernamevalue2    |
| --------- | ------------------ | ------------------ |
| 2020-01-01| [value1, value2]   |                    |
| 2020-01-01|                    | [value10, value11] |
| 2020-02-01| [value20, value21] |                    |
```

I am not able to properly convert a dictionary key with list values on separate rows.
Also, I wanted to avoid nested for loops to optimize the code.

Comment: `I wanted to avoid nested for loops to optimize the code` - performance is important?

Comment: @jezrael - yes. It could be millions of values and could slow down the execution I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
df = (pd.json_normalize(r, ['value', 'columns'], ['timestamp']).explode('values')
        .assign(inst=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
        .pivot_table(index=['inst', 'timestamp'], columns='innername', 
                     values='values', aggfunc='first')
        .droplevel('inst').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    timestamp innernamevalue1 innernamevalue2
0  2020-01-01          value1         value10
1  2020-02-01         value20             NaN
2  2020-01-01          value2         value11
3  2020-02-01         value21             NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with enumerate for processing duplicated `timestamps`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

r = data["data"]["items"]

d = defaultdict(dict)

for i in r:
    t = i["timestamp"]
    cols = i["value"]["columns"]
    for col in cols:
        for j, v in enumerate(col['values']):
            d[col['innername']][(j, t)] = v
         
df = pd.DataFrame(d).droplevel(0).rename_axis('timestamp').reset_index()
print (df)
    timestamp innernamevalue1 innernamevalue2
0  2020-01-01          value1         value10
1  2020-01-01          value2         value11
2  2020-02-01         value20             NaN
3  2020-02-01         value21             NaN
```